# Yeoman, Grunt, AngularJS and error 404 on POST form

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to send a form with "POST" method with AngularJS. I use $http to send it but it always return "Cannot POST" and 404 error. The route is correct and only happens if I execute my app via Grunt (sending by "GET" works perfect). The app has been built using Yeoman.

I think that it has to be a silly problem but I cannot make it work.

The view:

```
<form name="formLogin" ng-submit="login()">

<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="user">User</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" ng-model="user">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="pass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" ng-model="pass">
    </li>

</ul>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

The controller:

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $resource) {


    $scope.login = function() {

      var config = {
        url: 'php/login.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            user: $scope.user,
            pass: $scope.pass
        }
      }; // configuration object

      $http(config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success');
            if (data.status) {
              // succefull login

            } else {
              // Wrong login
            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');

        });

    };

  });
```

I use Grunt with:

```
grunt server
```

Why happens that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Thanks @passy. Edited with the code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused why `GET` should work in this case. The Grunt server just serves static files from your `app` and `.tmp` directories and your reference to the `.php` file is relative. So with the standard setup, an AJAX request to `php/login.php` would just return you the plain PHP source code of the file located in `app/php/login.php`, which is certainly not what you want.

You probably want to separate your backend from your frontend and have your PHP application in a different location. This could either be under a different location (e.g. `/api/login.php`) or a different host `https://api.example.com/login.php`. Mixing your Yeoman application with your API isn't a good idea.

However, if you are forced to keep them within one project, you can use [grunt-php](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php) to start a local PHP server from your Gruntfile.

Comment: thanks @passy. With "GET works perferct" I mean I don't get any 404 error. I tried a lot of things and I cannot make POST method work. Like you said, maybe backend should be in different location (then, use JSONP) but I don't understand why "POST" doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Even though you're getting back a 200, I don't think it's what you actually want. The grunt server just serves static files, so it will serve you the PHP source code if you hit the URL of the PHP file. It simply returns an error code if you use POST, PUT or any other unsupported method, because it doesn't have any behavior for it.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. It has to be something related with method unsupported. It's just driving me crazy the 404 error but I suppose that's the way I get notified that I can't make POST.

Answer (score 0):

Angular by default sends http post requests as `application/json` and not as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which may cause problems. Change your application to accept `application/json` or replace `application/json` with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post` and serialize form yourself. [More details in Angular.js doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) in section Setting HTTP headers.

Comment: Thank you @ivoszz. I tried that but I still get the 404 error on POST. If I execute my app without "Grunt server" command it works, so I think that my problem is Grunt with POST method (and me doing something wrong, of course ;) )

Comment: Just a quick idea, did you enabled CORS on the server and client? If you run your application directly from your server you probably load your client angular app from this server. If you run grunt server, you run another server and your requests are now [CORS requests](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). But I am not sure if this causes your problem.

Comment: Yes, I did but the same :(