# Yeoman,Grunt, AngularJS 404 cannot Post /

Tags: angularjs, routes, gruntjs, sails.js, yeoman

I have this little angular app on the frontend which is a food list. So write a food and click submit and it will show the list.
When I add a food I query my backend wich is a sails app at localhost:1337 and it gets updated. The problem is I get redirected to
localhost:9000/#/food and get 404.
This is the faulty request

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image        /webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:sails.sid=s%3A8gIjNxaZVE9dMr7nonXJzEaQ9hUcvcHm.Sp0K6ezep%2F7Y%2BV6TivtdRxqiBV    2S1LdH2IDNPWS9Ikk
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 137B2031-138E-4B6B-A3AE-    FB8EE96E9015

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: keep-alive
content-length: 14
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 12:21:51 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

The other request that gets code 200 and update the server model looks like this:

```
OPTIONS /food HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:9000
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 137B2031-138E-4B6B-A3AE-    FB8EE96E9015

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, access-control-allow-origin,     authorization,X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
Allow:             GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,TRACE,COPY,LOCK,MKCOL,MOVE,PURGE,PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,    UNLOCK,REPORT,MKACTIVITY,CHECKOUT,MERGE,M-    SEARCH,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,UNSUBSCRIBE,PATCH,SEARCH,CONNECT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 23 Feb 2015 12:21:51 GMT
set-cookie: sails.sid=s%3A_kBdyRZgZ23Gh9YLkZfWBgnMody-    jq-S.IY71%2BhJiBxTd19YIG2tgS2EOn1LPT%2BD9QAEQWtVB%2FbE; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>
```

At first I was looking at sails but I have CORS enabled and everything just like this:
https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate/blob/master/backend/config/cors.js
So maybe it's more an angular issue. The request that fails is from the frontend to itself so just a redirect on itself when it has been updated on the server. I don't get why the request is denied...
If you want to take a look at the code:
http://okamuuu.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/10/135240

Issues seem the same as this [Yeoman, Grunt, AngularJS and error 404 on POST form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123042/yeoman-grunt-angularjs-and-error-404-on-post-form) but that doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently your request is going to the port 9000:

```
Host: localhost:9000
```

Yet you said your app is running at port 1337.

So, in your `$http` requests, you **need to specify the port**. Otherwise, it will use the port your browser is currently connected to (9000) and there's no app there!

So, instead of

```
$http.get('/someUrl')
```

Try

```
$http.get('http://localhost:1337/someUrl')
```

Comment: That's already what I'm doing. Sails is running on port 1337 and angular on 9000

Comment: But the **request being made by angular** is going to port 9000.